# My 3 year old Jack Russell is attacking my 5 month old Yorkie without cause suddenly. Will nutering my Yorkie stop the attacks. Please help

Tags: dogs

I adopted a Yorkie puppy about 4 months ago and my Jack Russell and him got on so well and they were the perfect pair and best friends. Then suddenly about 3 weeks ago my Jack Russell went for my Yorkie and didn't bite. Last week he attacked him badly and my little guy landed up in hospital. I have separated them now but will neutering stop these attacks or make them worse? I don't want to loose either as I them both dearly.

Comment: How is the history of your older dog? Former owners? Socialized? Neutered?

Comment: Hi Chris. Thank you so much for answering. He had very little socializing but I have done alot of socializing with him since I got him a year ago and has been amazing in a pack situation. He was nuted about 8 months ago.